# Random DNS errors after change to nsswitch.conf

Tags: dns, hosts, getent

I recently installed my EPSON L3150 printer's drivers and about the same time I started having weird (and random) DNS name resolution errors in some applications (ssh, nextcloud-client), that I can only fix by restarting the `NetworkManager` service:

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

For example:

```
$ ssh example.mydomain
ssh: Could not resolve hostname example.mydomain: Name or service not known
```

Another example is getent, which returns nothing and exits with code 2:

```
$ getent hosts example.mydomain

$ echo $?
2
```

But nslookup works fine:

```
$ nslookup example.mydomain
...
Name:   example.mydomain
Address: 192.168.0.10
```

I narrowed it down to my `nsswitch.conf` file, which I blame my printer installer for changing it. I found a `nsswitch.conf.bak` lying besides a `nsswitch.conf`, created at the same time that I installed the printer drivers using `dnf install epson/*.rpm`.

The file had this change in the hosts line:

```
-hosts:      files dns myhostname
+hosts:      files myhostname mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
```

So the question is, why does the "new" configuration fail so randomly? How can I prevent it? I don't think just restoring the original file would be a solution since the new file seems to be auto-generated, it says so right at the top:

> Generated by authselect on Sat Feb 12 18:53:06 2022

Uninstalling the driver would also not be a solution.

**EDIT**:

The culprit seems to be `systemd-resolved`. My network config is managed by NetworkManager and I setup two DNSs:

```
$ nmcli con show my-lan
...
ipv4.dns 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
```

It seems that whenever my computer wakes up from sleep, NetworkManager falls back to the second DNS:

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
...
Link 2 (enp39s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
       DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
        DNS Domain: mydomain
```

Thus causing `systemd-resolve example.mydomain` to fail (because 8.8.8.8 can't resolve my domain):

> query: resolve call failed: 'example.mydomain' not found

I guess it's a bug in NetworkManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]` is needed for multicast DNS for the Epson printer.

`resolve [!UNAVAIL=return]` enables name resolution through `systemd-resolved` (see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/nss-resolve.html).

If the command `systemctl status systemd-resolved` gives back `Unit systemd-resolved.service could not be found.` you may safely remove `resolve [!UNAVAIL=return]` from the `hosts` line. After that, resolving should be back to normal.

Comment: `systemd-resolved` seems to be active and running, so maybe the issue is resolved itself? I will try to debug it

Comment: Okay after digging for while the culprit seems to be `systemd-resolved`. The explanation is a bit long so I will put in in an update to the OP